# Change style depending on orientation

Tags: android, coding-style, screen-orientation

is it possible to define a style for portrait orientation and another for landscape so when the device is rotated the change is automatic, or it has to be done programmatically ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your `/res` folder, make a new folder called `layout-land` and put your `main.xml` in there. it will switch to that layout for landscape.

Comment: You wont put just a copy of your main.xml. You create a new one that looks nice in the landscape mode. Then the system will automatically use this layout when the screen switches.